# SQL ANT TASK ERROR: Class Not Found: JDBC driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver could not be loaded

Tags: sql, eclipse, ant

I want to run an SQL query using the ant tasks, and I am using the SQLServerDriver (sqljdbc.jar). This jar file is located where I have all of my jars needed to run the application

> (WebContent/WEB-INF/lib)

This directory is my classpath which I defined it in another TASK Command:

```
<!-- Define el classpath que es utilizado para compilar los archivos -->
<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${libs.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>
```

This jar file is also indicated in my ecplise external jar files. 
The ant command that I am trying to run is the following:

```
<target name="db.query" description="Ejecuta un query de SQL">
    <sql driver="${db.driverT}" url="${db.urlT}" userid="${db.userT}" 
            password="${db.passwordT}" print="TRUE">
        SELECT * FROM T007_EDO;
    </sql>
</target>
```

What should I do to correct my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question was to simply add the line to my db.query task.

> classpathref="classpath"

So I have my classpath deffinition of the place where the jar file is located in:

```
<path id="classpath">
<fileset dir="${libs.dir}">
    <include name="*.jar" />
</fileset>
```

And I reference that in my ant task:

```
<target name="db.query" description="Ejecuta un query de SQL">
<sql driver="${db.driverT}" url="${db.urlT}" userid="${db.userT}" 
        password="${db.passwordT}" print="TRUE" classpathref="classpath">
    SELECT * FROM T007_EDO;
</sql>
```

Comment: Yes, reading the manual of the sql task would have told you that was the solution. Your self-response misses to show the classpathref in the sql task though.