# How to run a SQL script in Jenkins by invoking ANT?

Tags: jdbc, ant, jenkins

I am trying to use Jenkins to execute a SQL script that is in my source control. To do this, I created a build task to invoke ANT. My ANT version is 1.9.4.

Here is the build file that I am calling

```
<project name="VResources-Reset">
<sql
    driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER_NAME:1433;databaseName=Automation"
    userid="USERID"
    password="PWD"      
    src="C:\\SvyDeploy\\DEV\\Sprint\\Automation\\Database\\Viewpoint\\View Resources\\VResources - Reset Users.sql"/>
<classpath>
    <pathelement location="C:\\SvyDeploy\\DEV\\Sprint\\Automation\\libs\\sqljdbc4.jar"/>
</classpath>
</project>
```

I have also tried using `org.database.jdbcDriver` as the driver.

When I try to build my project in Jenkins, I am always getting the below error and can't figure out why. ANT and Jenkins are very new to me, so I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Can someone please point out what that is?

```
Class Not Found: JDBC driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver could not be loaded
```

Comment: Check this out: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734679/sql-ant-task-error-class-not-found-jdbc-driver-com-microsoft-sqlserver-jdbc-sq

Answer (score 0):

Hope classPath should be passed inside sql element.
Please try this..

```
<project name="VResources-Reset">
<sql driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" url="jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER_NAME:1433;databaseName=Automation"
    userid="USERID"
    password="PWD"      
    src="C:\\SvyDeploy\\DEV\\Sprint\\Automation\\Database\\Viewpoint\\View Resources\\VResources - Reset Users.sql">
<classpath>
    <pathelement location="C:\\SvyDeploy\\DEV\\Sprint\\Automation\\libs\\sqljdbc4.jar"/>
</classpath>
</sql>
</project>
```